# How to use source-level multithreading in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, cpu, multicore

I need to gain performance by using 2 hardware CPUs on MS Windows. I write the following code:

```
#include "windows.h"

int main1(int argc, CHAR* argv[])
{
    // ...
}

int main2(int argc, CHAR* argv[])
{
    // ...
}
```

to write two main functions - one for every CPU. The compiler tells me:

```
D:/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am i doing wrong? How can i write two mains to make them run on two different CPUs? `_tmain1, _tmain2` does not help either.

Comment: Is `threads` the term you're looking for?

Comment: For Intel processors you can use the following code void main0() void main1() { { } }

Comment: How does this work? Do you need to compile with the intel compiler?

Comment: `[citation needed]` and -1 until one is provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create one main, and start another thread for which you set the processor affinity.

pseudocode:

```
int main1(){...}
int main2(){...}

int main()
{
  main2_thread = StartThreed( main2 );
  SetProcessorAffinity( this_thread, 0 );
  SetProcessorAffinity( main2_thread, 1 );
  main1();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can only have one `main` function in a process.  From that function, you can start multiple threads.  Here's a very short example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>

void thread_func(void* v)
{
   std::cout << "Hello: " << *(int*)v << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   int i = 1;
   ::_beginthread(thread_func, 0, &i);

   int i2 = 2;
   _beginthread(thread_func, 0, &i2);

   Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: This is a rather bad example for a beginner... I'd say at least provide (or point out the need for) a join + cleanup (I am a victim of a poorly written C book that screwed me up badly many, many years ago - I would have learned that stuff a lot faster if not that book).

Answer (score 2):

Either make just one main and launch multiple threads from there. Or one main, where you could fork several processes.